# My e-guitar doesn't get amplified by the amp

Tags: amplifiers, cable

Long story short, after leaving my guitar for a few months, I decided to start practicing again. I plugged my amp and every led blinked at it should. I took my jack and plugged it into the amp. No buzz was emitted by The cable as I touched the tip and inserted into the guitar.  No amplification. I decided to leave the guitar and try later. After an hour I tried again and somehow it worked again. I played for a while and the decided to power off my amp. After I while I wanted to play again, and the same thing happend. Is it my cable or my amp?

Comment: What model is the amp?

Comment: It's a boss katana 50

Comment: How hard can it be to try a different cable?   Test one thing at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Several times I've found this with amps not used for a while. The headphone and/or line out socket is switched, and the contacts don't work that well, resulting in no sound. A spray with switch cleaner and plugging/unplugging a jack into these ports had the amps working again.

However, with scant info., it could be one of many diverse problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's your cable or your amp.  Or, as @Tim suggested, a dirty socket either on the guitar or the amp (more likely the amp, as you got no buzz when touching the plug).